# How to identify an element without using xpath when id name is not available in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There are few elements in an UI page without ID. I will download a particular version and then save all the current element tags and give to script as input, since few elements are not having id, this is causing script failures.

How can I locate the element without using Xpath.
Is there any simple way when there is no fixed id.

Comment: Any data attribute on that element would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no." Sorry. All of the usual ways (by id, class, etc.) are relying on the same css information to locate elements. Xpath just shows all the ugly plumbing out in public. I don't think xpath has ever been described as "simple" but there is usually a way, using xpath, to find any element.

Xpath can be intimidating. Start with a plugin that will generate the xpath for you, once you click on an element. Usually the xpath generated will be extremely long and inefficient, but with practice you can see what can be trimmed and what is crucial. And to do that, *also* use a plugin that will "check" your xpath to see if it can find the element. Once you can find it (and ONLY the element you want) try trimming it to see if you can still find it with the abbreviated xpath locator.

Answer (score 0):

[reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJmeY.png)Don't be afraid of Xpaths. It's relatively easy to grab an Xpath using the **Google Chrome browser**. Navigate to your page and open *Developer tools*. *Right-click on the particular tag* for which you need an Xpath. *Copy -> Xpath*